# local directory #include paths in Visual Studio 2022 aren't resolved by Intellisense for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I've got the following include statement:

```cpp
#include "MazeParser.h"
```

This compiles perfectly. However, in Intellisense, it doesn't resolve (a screenshot is attached). I can include STL headers and all that, but I just can't include files in my local directory.

Funnily enough, if I open the header file MazeParser.h in another tab in Visual Studio, then after refreshing Intellisense the path resolves and Intellisense works. After closing Visual Studio and reopening it, the path no longer resolves.

[image: maze parser header error]

However, this is annoying and difficult to work with since every time I open VS I need to open every header file in a new tab and refresh Intellisense. I thought adding the header files to my solution's Header Files would solve the issue, but no dice.

[image: header files]

I've read that a bad include path can lead to this situation. However, even explicitly adding my project path to Include Directories doesn't work.
[image: vsc++ settings]

I'm using Parallels on my Mac if that makes a difference.

Comment: What happens if you create a brand new (empty) project from one of VC's project templates, then try to build-and-run it?

Comment: @Dai Strange, when I make the project the shared drive between my Mac and Windows VM, Intellisense doesn't work, but when I make it on my Windows drive, it works just fine. I would like a way to continue working on my Mac drive though. Could it be a CRLF / CR discrepancy?

Comment: It won't be anything to do with line-endings (line-endings haven't been a real Mac/PC issue since OS X came out in 2001). But how is the "shared drive" mounted in both OSes? (Because if it's mounted in Windows as an SMB share then that might cause issues; I'm not familiar with Parallels, but some VM/hosts have really dodgy shared-files functionality - which should only be used for transferring data rather than as a working-folder for a VS project...)

Comment: `Header Files` is Solution Explorer is not a directory, it is a *filter*. And placing header files in there does not allow to resolve them as local includes. `#include "..."` syntax should be used only when header file is located in the same file system folder as the file that includes it. Btw there is a button at toolbar at Solution Explorer which switched view to display file system rather than filters.